# How to query table based on value from POST method in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am fairly new to codeigniter.

I have the following code in my views/check_availability/index.php file:

```
<?php $type = $_POST['type']; ?>

<a href="/reservation/check_availability/create">Create Reservation</a>

<?php foreach ($check_availability as $check_availability_item): ?>

    <h2><?php echo $check_availability_item['room_type'] ?></h2>
    <div id="main">
        <?php echo $check_availability_item['room_description'] ?>
    </div>
    <p><a href="check_availability/<?php echo $check_availability_item['id'] ?>">View article</a></p>

<?php endforeach ?>
```

This is my code under models/check_availabiliy_model.php file

```
public function check_availability($type = FALSE)
{
    if ($type === FALSE)
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('lf_rooms');
        return $query->result_array();
    }

    $query = $this->db->get_where('lf_rooms', array('type' => $type));
    return $query->row_array();
}
```

This is the code in my controllers/check_availability.php file

```
public function index()
{
    $data['check_availability'] = $this->check_availability_model->check_availability();
    $data['title'] = 'Available Roooms';

    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('check_availability/index', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

Under views/check_availability/index.php file I want to filter the room_type field when I call the check_availability function based on the value from POST method like $type = $_POST['type'].

Currently this is the code that I used to query all the record from lf_rooms table:

```
<?php foreach ($check_availability as $check_availability_item): ?>
```

but how can I pass the value of $type variable to check_availability function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get the `POST` parameter in the controller, query the database accordingly and only display the results in the view. The view should not hold any logic.

```
public function index()
{
    $type = $this->input->post('type', TRUE);

    $data['check_availability'] = $this->check_availability_model->
                                  check_availability($type);
}
```

Comment: i have followed your code but when I debug the $type variable the value is FALSE. i have this code to call the check_availability url: `<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="http://localhost/reservation/check_availability/">
  <input type="text" name="type" id="textfield" />
  <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" />
</form>`

Comment: hi, i'm so sorry but you answer is correct. my problem is with this line `return $query->row_array();` i supposed to use this code `return $query->result_array();`. thank you very much.